# How to install multiple openjdk versions on alpine-based docker container

Tags: java, docker, jenkins, slave

I wish to install jdk7 and jdk8 on an alpine container side by side. I would like to pick jdk7 only if an env variable is set.

I've chained `FROM openjdk:7-alpine` and `FROM openjdk:8-alpine`, but regardless of their relative order, the latter one overwrites the former. So, I am left with only 1 installation as seen in `'/usr/lib/jvm'`.

**Why I need this:**

I need this setup for a slave container for Jenkins. Now, jenkins remoting jar runs ONLY on jdk8 now. So, I need it. Plus, since I am spawning this container for a project which needs jdk7 as default jdk, I need that too.

**My Dockerfile:** https://github.com/ankurshashcode/docker-slave/blob/alpine/Dockerfile

Answer (score 12):

You should keep it simple and use one base image.
Use `openjdk7` as base image, install openjdk8 as a package.
This will overwrite openjdk7 as the default JDK while leaving it in the image.

```
   # Example Dockerfile
   FROM openjdk:7-alpine
   RUN apk add --no-cache openjdk8

   # Other setup...
```

### Verify

```
$> java -version
openjdk version "1.8.0_131"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 3.4.0) (Alpine 8.131.11-r2)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.131-b11, mixed mode)

$> ls /usr/lib/jvm/
default-jvm       java-1.7-openjdk  java-1.8-openjdk
```

Answer (score 11):

You can use [Docker multistage build](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/eng-image/multistage-build/) to achieve that. You would basically copy the java installation from one image into another image. Here is what the dockerfile might look like:

```
FROM openjdk:7-alpine as java7

FROM openjdk:8-alpine
COPY --from=java7 /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7-openjdk /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7-openjdk
```

Now you will have both java installations with the jdk7 installation being under `/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7-openjdk`